# How to write a function where input is row of the dataframe and output is another dataframe?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a table that has 3 columns, name, start and end. I'm trying to write (preferably using tidyverse) function that will take each row of that table and create (later bind all outputs) dataframe based on the logic. Obviously I need seq, but I can't figure out what function use to process the input. I tried with map_df and rowwise but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Here is example

input

```
name|start|end
A   | 1   | 3
B   | 1   | 4
```

expected output

```
Name|value
A   |1
A   |2
A   |3
B   |1
B   |2
B   |3
B   |4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
      transmute(name, value = map2(start, end, `:`)) %>%
      unnest(c(value))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  name  value
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A         1
#2 A         2
#3 A         3
#4 B         1
#5 B         2
#6 B         3
#7 B         4
```

---

Or with `rowwise`

```
df1 %>%
   rowwise %>%
   transmute(name, value = list(start:end)) %>%
   unnest(c(value))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `stack` and `Map`

```
stack(setNames(do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, df1[-1])), df1$name))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c('A', 'B'), start = c(1, 1), end = c(3, 4))
```

Comment: this is amazing. exactly what I need.

Comment: Done, need to wait few more minutes to accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the `unnest` isn't the `c()` unnecessary? Just testing myself.  Agree it works either way but curious @akrun

Comment: @ChuckP   It is just that if you have more columns, it can be. wrapped in `c`.  I just put iit that way for a general case and sometimes, people may come back with a query that `unnest(value1, value2)` didn't work